# Collapsing toolbar in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

How to build an Instagram profile page using Jetpack compose. I've tried multiple libraries like [NestedScrollView](https://github.com/Tlaster/NestedScrollView), [CollapsingToolbar](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar) to get collapsable/scrollable Topbar but they are not looking smooth. It's easy to build with XML using CoordinatorLayout.

Expected Scroll:-
[Instagram Profile Page](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/78361787/151689860-223832d1-6ff6-45ee-b459-ea2111429d62.gif)

Using NestedScrollView Library:-
[NestedScrollView](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/78361787/151689887-b6a0c58a-b52d-4a49-b545-c80ef7039fd7.gif)

Comment: I also have the same issue, did you find anything?

Answer (score 4):

This layout is easy to implement with `LazyColumn` and `stickyHeader`:

```
LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    item {
        Text("Header")
    }
    stickyHeader {
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = 0) {
            repeat(4) {
                Tab(selected = it == 0, onClick = {}) {
                    Text(
                        it.toString()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    items(100) {
        Text(it.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: every tab will have lazyColumn/LazyVertical grid items which will have pagination

Comment: How to add `HorizontalPager` which will switch based on swipe or tab change

Comment: @Phil Dukhow Perhaps you know how to fix my issue, could you take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326733/collapsingtoolbar-in-compose-with-button-sticky

Answer (score 0):

I found a library to creating profile layout same as Instagram. github link :- [compose-collapsing-toolbar](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar)

1. Add the following line to the dependencies block in your app level build.gradle

```
implementation "me.onebone:toolbar-compose:2.3.5"
```

2. Use the following code for collapsing toolbar

   ```
   CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
       state = state,
       scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.EnterAlwaysCollapsed,
       enabled = true,
       toolbar = { // create header layout here }
   ) {
       // create main layout here
   }
   ```

Here i have created a sample profile layout with tab layout

```
package // replace with your package name

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerState
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ShoppingCart
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Tab
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.totel.testing.ui.theme.TestingTheme
import me.onebone.toolbar.CollapsingToolbarScaffold
import me.onebone.toolbar.ScrollStrategy
import me.onebone.toolbar.rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestingTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    ProfileLayout()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProfileLayout() {

    val state = rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState()

    Box {
        CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = state,
            scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.EnterAlwaysCollapsed,
            enabled = true,
            toolbar = {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .parallax(0.5f)
                        .height(300.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                }

            }
        ) {

            TabContent()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TabContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
        3
    })

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        Tabs(pagerState = pagerState)
        TabsContent(pagerState = pagerState)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Tabs(pagerState: PagerState) {
    val list = listOf(
        "Home" to Icons.Default.Home,
        "Shopping" to Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
        "Settings" to Icons.Default.Settings
    )


    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        contentColor = Color.Black,

        ) {
        list.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            // on below line we are creating a tab.
            Tab(
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = list[index].second, contentDescription = null,
                        tint = if (pagerState.currentPage == index) Color.Blue else Color.Black
                    )
                },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        list[index].first,
                        color = if (pagerState.currentPage == index) Color.Blue else Color.Black
                    )
                },
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,

                onClick = {

                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TabsContent(pagerState: PagerState) {

    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> TabContentScreen(data = "Welcome to Home Screen")
            1 -> TabContentScreen(data = "Welcome to Shopping Screen")
            2 -> TabContentScreen(data = "Welcome to Settings Screen")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabContentScreen(data: String) {
    val itemsList = (0..500).toList()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        items(items = itemsList) { item ->
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp),
                text = "$data $item",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
            )
        }
    }
}
```