# CollapsingToolbar in Compose with Button Sticky

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to implement the CollapsingToolbar in `Compose` but the examples I've found through the internet don't accomplish my needs.
I used to use xml and the same layout was :

```
-AppBarLayout
  -CollapsingToolbarLayout
    -ConstraintLayout
      -ImageView(parallax, centerCrop)
      -Toolbar
-NestedScrollView
-FloatingButton (anchorGravity="bottom|end")
-Button(sticky)
```

I've tried many things, but the hard thing is to have the `FloatingButton` (can be any other view not specially a `FAB`).

Demo :

[image]

The `parallax` effect I did it as follows :

```
Box(
   modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer { 
        translationy = -scroll.value.toFloat() / 2f
        alpha = (-1f / headerHeightPx) * scroll.value + 1
   }
) { Image... }
```

I also found the [`Compose Collapsing Toolbar library`](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar) but I'd prefer to not use any library if possible.

I've seen that there's a Material3 there's a [`TopAppBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TopAppBarDefaults) and perhaps it would work.

### Update

I've also tried the `Material3` library but is not working as expected since my behaviour is breaking the how it should be.

What I'm thinking is to create a `Box` or since I want elevation a `Surface` and on it, contain inside the `Icon` and the `Image` and also the center `Box`.

I've created a simple image to describe what I've thought and perhaps is a good way to start.

[image]

Here I'd need to link the scroll of the `List` and with the `.value` create the *animation* or change the `Alpha` of the `Image` and then once is *collapsed* add the `elevation` to the `Surface`.

In the second image the center box is not aligned the same way, but I don't want to change it, it was a miss paint.

So the recap should be :

Create this `Composable` and *fake* the `TopAppBar` so it should stop *collapsing* when the *height* is `56.dp` as the min size of the `TopAppBar`.

When scrolling the `Image` should animate or change it's alpha (or parallax effect) and then convert the background to white as a transition.

And then the problem I'm seeing is that I'd need to add some calculations to detect the behaviour of `exitUntilCollapsed` let's say I want to *un-collapse* once the first item of the list is visible.

Comment: I have created a sample application using compose. This may be helpful for you. https://github.com/vinay6kr/collapsing-toolbar-jetpack-compose-sample

Comment: Not what I'm looking at all, but it's an approach, I want the image become smaller when you are scrolling, and then change the background to white, I'd avoid having a Toolbar as hide and then change it, because I'll have problems with the centered box floating. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @StuartDTO what you ask for as so much moving parts but basically you need to change position, alpha and height based on scroll value proportion. Check start and end intervals of scroll you wish to use and change alpha or other properties using this range between initial and end value. Let's say, scroll range is between 100, and 200. and alpha is between 0.5 and 1f. You need to interpolate values from 100-200 range to 0.5f range, 150px scroll value should correspond to 0.75 and so on.

Comment: This is similar to slider range change based on drag position in pixel in slider source code. It can be done using scale and lerp functions.

Comment: @Thracian What I want is having this box using `translationY` the half of its height to be at the center and when scrolling be at the center also of the Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Just gave it a try according to your drawing suggestions:

```
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateDpAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Divider
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.BottomCenter
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.Center
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.CenterVertically
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.TopStart
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.max
import com.canopas.base.ui.AppTheme
import com.canopas.base.ui.ColorPrimary
import com.canopas.base.ui.White
import com.canopas.ui.R
import kotlin.math.min


Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val items = (1..100).map { "Item $it" }
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
        val scrollOffset: Float = min(
            1f,
            1 - (lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset / 200f + lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
        )
        val imageSize by animateDpAsState(targetValue = max(0.dp, 300.dp * scrollOffset))
        Box(contentAlignment = Center) {
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_intro_screen_image1),
                modifier = Modifier.size(imageSize),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                contentDescription = "Food Category thumbnail"
            )
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .background(Color.White).align(BottomCenter),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, verticalAlignment = CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(text = "Title", modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 12.dp).fillMaxSize(), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            }
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier = Modifier.align(TopStart)) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "")
        }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f),
            lazyListState,
        ) {
            items(items) {
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    Modifier
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), color = ColorPrimary)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = ColorPrimary,
                ),
                elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
                    defaultElevation = 0.dp,
                    pressedElevation = 0.dp,
                    disabledElevation = 0.dp,
                    hoveredElevation = 0.dp,
                    focusedElevation = 0.dp
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Button",
                    color = White,
                    style = AppTheme.typography.buttonStyle,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 6.dp)
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is not collapsing, could you add the full imports and the code where I can copy and paste and test it out? Thanks

Comment: Added imports in edited answer

Comment: But this is not collapsing I don't know what's missing

Comment: If you copy it , it works as expected. Just tried it. This answer is a life saver