How to make Box with contents scroll at the same time with TopAppBar
I'm implementing a Screen where I'm showing a TopAppBar overlayed on top of a composable. The idea is to have the composable in the background with the TopAppBar on top of it.
All works well, however I cannot get the composable to scroll at the same time with the TopAppBar. The TopAppBar respects the scrolling configuration, though not the composable.
Here's my set-up:
Scaffold and scrollBehavior
 val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
 
 Scaffold(
         modifier = modifier
             .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
         topBar = {
             TopBar(..., scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
         }
 ) { padding ->
     PullToRefreshLazyColumn(...) {
         ... normal content here ...
     }
 }

TopBar being:
...
@Composable
fun TopBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    context: Context,
    uiState: UiState,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean,
    navigateUp: () -> Unit,
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior,
    ...
) {
    Box {
        if (uiState == UiState.Success) {
            MyComposable(
                modifier = modifier,
                context = context,
                ...
            )
        }

        TopAppBar(
            title = { },
            modifier = Modifier,
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            navigationIcon = {
                if (canNavigateBack) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = navigateUp,
                        colors = IconButtonColors(
                            contentColor = Color.White,
                            containerColor = Color.Black.copy(0.5f),
                            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
                            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer
                        )
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
            actions = {
                ...
            },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
        )
    }
}

MyComposable
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    context: Context,
    ...
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ...

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(300.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            if (...) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                   ... Image and button composables here ...
            } else if (...) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    ... Image and button composables here ...
            } else {
                ... Button composable here ...
            }

            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = !expanded }
            ) {
                ... Text button composables here ...
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
        ) {
            ... Text composables here ...
        }
    }
}

What I've tried
I tried putting Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection) on all composables except TopAppBar, or just only on Box composables, or Box and Column composables and also tried verticalScroll on Column composable.
No matter what I've tried, MyComposable remains pinned when I scroll down the screen, while the TopAppBar correctly hides.
Default state (TopAppBar and Box show correctly at top of the screen):

Scrolled state (TopAppBar disappeared while Box still shows):

Has anyone else ran into this issue and if so have you managed to solve it and how?

Maybe you can get some idea from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76382248/19212377

Thanks. I tried to implement that solution, though it doesn't work with my setup.
